# Visual studio 2012 can't find files inside of Include Directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

When I compile in VS2012, I get error that cant find files that should be in the `#include` directory, `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include"`.

I've attempted to resolve this by copying the `#include` directory from VS2010 in `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include"`

This presented more errors. I've also tried changing the path for the #include directory (in Project/Properties/VC++ directories) as suggested [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/762015/include-and-libraries-directories-not-setup-correctly-for-c-if-vs2010-already-installed) with

```
$(VCInstallDir)include;$(VCInstallDir)atlmfc\include;$(WindowsSdkDir)include;$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);$(FrameworkSDKDir)\include.
```

I've also reinstalled VS2012 several times to no avail. Does anybody have a solution.

Comment: Can you specify which header files are not found by VS 2012  out of the box?

Comment: At the moment its stdint.h.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a known bug described here: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/762015/include-and-libraries-directories-not-setup-correctly-for-c-if-vs2010-already-installed

The installer has a bug if 2010 was previously installed. I experienced this one.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft supports stdint from VS 2012 on. Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874765%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
#include <cstdint>
```